# Is char* used as the location of a byte in memory?

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I know what this code does: copies the content from the memory pointed by &x into the file, for sizeof(double) bytes; reads the file and copies into the memory pointed by &y, for sizeof(double) bytes.

```
double x,y;
std::ofstream out( "abc.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
out.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&x), sizeof(double));
out.close();

std::ifstream in( "abc.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
in.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y), sizeof(double));
in.close();
```

From what I understand, when doing binary IO, the data flowing between the file and RAM should be in terms of bytes. Then the &x address should be passed as a byte location: something like out.write( reinterpret_cast< const byte*>(&x), sizeof(double)) would make sense. However C++ does not define a type byte, and here the char* can be understood as a byte location, am I right? I note that the size of char is identical as one byte, they are both 8 bits.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Yes.

Comment: `char` is defined as being 1 byte and able to alias any type, that's why the read and write functions use pointer to char

Comment: oops yes types wrongly @M.M

Comment: Yes. char is a "Byte", but seems unsigned char is "better Byte"

Comment: Thanks guys I think I understand now. A few years back that lousy lecturer says char is equivalent to int....that leads to these panic.

Comment: byte / char in expression (by value) is compatible with int (concrete : in expression is implicit converted to int). But when pass by address these are distinct types.

Comment: Also in C (not C++) a char literal is equivalent to int in size (or at least it was, may have changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the size of char is 1 byte in c++.

Other than that sizes are a little more fluid. Which is why some vendors offer non-standard extensions which guarantee sizes. For instance in Microsoft VC there is the WORD which is 16 bits.

Check out this page for more info: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types